# Error: Cannot open include file: 'MQTTAsync.h': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, mqtt, paho

OS -Windows 10 x64

Library mqtt
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.9.15

Programming Language - C++17

Installed **paho-mqtt paho-mqttpp3 paho-mqttpp3[ssl]** using vcpkg

I am creating a c++ program using mqtt.
But whenever I am using below given header

`#include <mqtt/async_client.h>`

It is giving following error

`d:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\mqtt\async_client.h(27): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'MQTTAsync.h': No such file or directory`

But MQTTAsync.h file is available on the given location
**`D:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt`**

I had followed below link by creating new console project

**https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg/issues/1848**

Still issue is not getting resolved

Comment: What happens if you change it to `#include <paho-mqtt/async_client.h>`

Comment: paho-mqtt doesn't contain `async_client.h`. async_client.h is inside mqtt. async_client using  `MQTTAsync.h` and that time it gives error. `Cannot open include file: 'MQTTAsync.h': No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

Verify the correct name in your vcpkg-directory.

In my case that would be `C:\Users\USERNAME\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\paho-mqtt`

Here you will see that the header file you are looking for is actually called MQTTAsync.h

To add it in your project you will have to change your inlcude to `#include <paho-mqtt/MQTTAsync.h>`